# Rabbit MQ org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I am facing unknown-host exception for below code. I am not sure what is wrong with code.

---

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class RabbitListenerContainerFactory {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitListenerContainerFactory.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2Subscriber receiver;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel;

     public RabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        printContainerStartMsg();
    }
    private void printContainerStartMsg() {
        logger.info("----------- Scrubber Container Starts   --------------");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer queueListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) { 
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberQueueName());
       // container.setQueueNames("SampleQueue"); /*This just for testing.. !*/
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        container.setDeclarationRetries(5);// This is default to 3, We can twick this and move this to prop
        container.setPrefetchCount(100); //Tell the broker how many messages to send to each consumer in a single request.
        return container;
    }

     @Bean
     MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(EPPQ2Subscriber receiver) {
         return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
     }

     /*@Bean
     MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapterWithChanel(EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel) {
         return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiverChanel);
     }*/

     @Bean
     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory () {
         final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
         connectionFactory.setAddresses(Arrays.toString(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts()));
            //connectionFactory.setHost(Arrays.toString(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts()));
            connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("hydra.services");
            connectionFactory.setPort(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPort());
            connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberUsername());
            connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPassword());
         return connectionFactory;
     }
}
```

I am able to see rabbit running on the host 
I can see admin console here http://hostname:15672/
Tel net is working 
Telnet hostname 15672
timeout 3 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/hostname/15672 '; echo $?

---

Here is log :

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException:host-name
```

---

Edit 1

```
    public class RabbitMqConfig {

    private String [] subscriberHosts;
    private int subscriberPort;

    private String [] publisherHosts;
    private int publisherPort;

    private String subscriberUsername;
    private String subscriberPassword;

    private String publisherUsername;
    private String publisherPassword;

    private String subscriberQueueName;
    private String publisherQueueName;
    private String publisherTopic;
    private String routingKey;

    /**
     * 
     * @return -read queue hosts
     */
    public String[] getSubscriberHosts() {
        return subscriberHosts;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return -read queue port
     */
    public int getSubscriberPort() {
        return subscriberPort;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return -write queue hosts
     */
    public String[] getPublisherHosts() {
        return publisherHosts;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return -write queue port
     */
    public int getPublisherPort() {
        return publisherPort;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return -Read Queue user name
     */
    public String getSubscriberUsername() {
        return subscriberUsername;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return Read Queue password
     */
    public String getSubscriberPassword() {
        return subscriberPassword;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return -Write Queue user name
     */
    public String getPublisherUsername() {
        return publisherUsername;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return  -Write Queue password
     */
    public String getPublisherPassword() {
        return publisherPassword;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return  -Write Queue name
     */
    public String getSubscriberQueueName() {
        return subscriberQueueName;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return  --Read Queue name
     */
    public String getPublisherQueueName() {
        return publisherQueueName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getPublisherTopic() {
        return publisherTopic;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getRoutingKey() {
        return routingKey;
    }

@PostConstruct
    public void getAIMCredentails() {
        tempApiCallMock();
    }


    private void tempApiCallMock() {
        String [] host = {"10.30.190.25"};
        this.subscriberHosts = host;
        this.subscriberPort = 5672;
        this.subscriberQueueName = "hydra.Syphon.q1";
        this.subscriberUsername = "dftp_subscriber";
        this.subscriberPassword = "dftp_subscriber";
        this.publisherHosts = host; 
        this.publisherPort = 5672;
        this.publisherUsername = "dftp_publisher";
        this.publisherPassword = "dftp_publisher";
    }
```

Thanks for Correcting me I changed the port to 5672 But still the same issue.
and my telnet host 5672 works

Comment: Would be great to see you `RabbitMqConfig` and what exactly you use there for `getSubscriberHosts()`. Bear in mind that `15672` is an HTTP port for the RabbitMQ management console. The AMQP port is `5672` by default. Be sure that you really use a right one there in your config.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - You can see RabbitMqConfig on Edit1

Comment: See `AbstractConnectionFactory.setAddresses()` JavaDocs and signature. It must not be a `String[]`.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/AbstractConnectionFactory.html  This is String not String [ ]

Comment: in my connection factory I have something like this 
connectionFactory.setAddresses(Arrays.toString(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts()));

Comment: That's not correct. It just must be a *comma-separated string*. Not a String representation of the array.

Comment: And Also I have question How do we set multi node Addresses. do we need construct the comma separated string

Comment: That's correct. See that `setAddresses()` JavaDoc: `host[:port],...`

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan. It is working!

Answer (score 0):

The `connectionFactory.setAddresses(Arrays.toString(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts()));`

is wrong. The `setAddresses()` expects a *comma-separate string*, not a string representation of the array.

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set addresses for clustering.
 * This property overrides the host+port properties if not empty.
 * @param addresses list of addresses with form "host[:port],..."
 */
public void setAddresses(String addresses) {
```